# Not Using Chrome Web Store Payment Processing as Payment Method for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, payment, chrome-web-store, tax

Hope everyone is well.

I have read the Chrome Web Store Developer Agreement which I believe has provided clarity on the matter, but just wanted to check with others who may have been down the same route...

Am I correct in thinking if building a paid Chrome Extension that you don't have to accept payment via the Chrome Web Store payment processing?

I ask, not because I want to avoid their 5% fee, but rather, I was looking at using a 'Merchant of Record' such as Paddle, 2Checkout or Fastspring as these services not only act as a payment processor but also obviously act as a reseller and in doing so take on all liability in regards charging, collecting and remitting the necessary sales tax, VAT & GST, therefore making things much easier for me in that regard.

I would greatly appreciate if anybody had any experience with this and could confirm this is possible as I currently believe it is.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is correct, according to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/overview#charging): you can use a custom payment solution different from Chrome Web Store payment.